# How to set default tab in jssor "tab slider text" jquery demo example

Tags: jquery, jssor

By now I have a pretty good grasp of how to get a JSSOR slide show up and running. I am currently employing the "[tab-slider-text.source.html](http://www.jssor.com/demos/tab-slider.html)" example as the model for a three tab panel, where each panel will be a week: TAB 1 will be "Previous Week", TAB 2 will be "This Week", and TAB 3 will be "Next Week".

The contents of each panel for each week will be a table with some data.

Logically, I want the middle tab, "This Week", to display by default when the user goes to the page.

I could make it so TAB 1 equals "This Week", but I don't think that looks like you would have a calendar. <- last week this week next week -> if you get the picture.

The demo page for this particular slide show example is here:
[Horizontal Tab Slider Demo](http://www.jssor.com/demos/tab-slider.html)

In mine, I'm only going to use three tabs, not five. And I want TAB #2, the middle tab, to be the default selected tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display #2 table at the beginning, please set `$StartIndex` value as 1.

```
var options {
   ...,
   $StartIndex: 1,
   ...
}
```